# Squid log flooded with 404 message

Tags: squid

I'm running squid on a server and, sometimes, the log gets flooded with messages caused by a specific host (192.168.1.20). These message I'm refering to is (`some.website.com` is not the actual website, it's just an example):

```
...

192.168.1.20 TCP_MISS/404 0 CONNECT some.website.com:443 - DIRECT/- -

...
```

In an attempt to stop these messages I added the following in `squid.conf` but the log kept being flooded with the same message:

```
acl disable-website dstdomain .website.com
cache deny disable-website
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some reason you don't just fix 192.168.1.20?

Answer (score 2):

`cache deny` asks Squid not to keep a cache of the matched URLs, but not to prevent users from accessing them; what you want here is `http_access deny disable-website`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try that. Soon I'll tell you if it worked :)